# Can you use if-else statement inside braces for an array in Python?

Tags: python, arrays, if-statement, numpy

I'm wondering if there is a nice way to use an if-else statement inside braces of an array in Python to assign values. What I would like is something like:

```
A = #some 2D array of length m by n, already initialized
A = np.float64(A)
val = someValue #any number, pick a number

A = [[val for j in range(n) if A[i][j] < val, else A[i][j]=A[i][j]] for i in range(m)]
```

Is there a nice way to do this? Alternatively, if numpy has a faster way to compute this that would be equally as good, if not better.

The longer way to do what I am trying to achieve would be something like

```
for i in range(m):
    for j in range(n):
        if A[i][j] < val:
            A[i][j] = val
```

The desired output is to set any values below a threshold to that threshold. I can do simpler if-statements with a 1D array such as

```
myArray = [otherArray[i] for i in range(theRange) if otherArray[i]>=value and otherArray[i]<=anotherValue]
```

This 1D example is not what I want. It's just an example of the type of coding block I'm looking for. It seems to be quicker at processing against the traditional if-else statements.

Comment: What is your expected output? You can use a *conditional expression*, but not in the way you are doing (you can't do assignments inside expressions, for example). It is extremely unclear to me what you are trying to achieve here.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I just revised my question.

Comment: `A[A < val] = val`

Comment: if it's too hard to understand how to _write_ the list comprehension, it will probably be equally hard to _read_ the list comprehension when you have to maintain the code. Why not stick to something more explicit and easier to understand?

Comment: The nested for loop is *much* clearer than the list comprehension, and doesn't unnecessarily allocate a new list.

Comment: @Lou: BrendanAbel's answer is a perfectly fine *python* answer.  If you are going to use numpy, however, hpaulj's answer is much better, and worth studying.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With numpy arrays we try avoid iteration (list comprehension). Sometimes it is needed, but in this case it is not:

```
In [403]: A=np.arange(16).reshape(4,4)    
In [404]: A1=A.astype(np.float64)    # better syntax for converting to float

In [405]: A1
Out[405]: 
array([[  0.,   1.,   2.,   3.],
       [  4.,   5.,   6.,   7.],
       [  8.,   9.,  10.,  11.],
       [ 12.,  13.,  14.,  15.]])
```

A boolean array that shows where the test is True/False:

```
In [406]: A1<5 
Out[406]: 
array([[ True,  True,  True,  True],
       [ True, False, False, False],
       [False, False, False, False],
       [False, False, False, False]], dtype=bool)
```

We can index with such a mask:

```
In [407]: A1[A1<5]=5

In [408]: A1
Out[408]: 
array([[  5.,   5.,   5.,   5.],
       [  5.,   5.,   6.,   7.],
       [  8.,   9.,  10.,  11.],
       [ 12.,  13.,  14.,  15.]])
```

`np.where` (and `np.nonzero`) return indices where the condition is True; `where` has a version that operates like the ternary operator (on each element):

```
In [410]: np.where(A<5,5,A)
Out[410]: 
array([[ 5,  5,  5,  5],
       [ 5,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 8,  9, 10, 11],
       [12, 13, 14, 15]])
```

We can also `clip` with `np.maximum`:

```
In [411]: np.maximum(A,5)
Out[411]: 
array([[ 5,  5,  5,  5],
       [ 5,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 8,  9, 10, 11],
       [12, 13, 14, 15]])

In [417]: A.clip(5,None)
Out[417]: 
array([[ 5,  5,  5,  5],
       [ 5,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 8,  9, 10, 11],
       [12, 13, 14, 15]])
```

Comment: Great examples, and you can do multiple conditions such as np.where((A < 3) | (A > 10), np.nan, A) but I have yet to find a simple method of identifying where A might be 'in' a list of values ie [3, 5, 9, 12, 2] without resorting to flattening, using a list compr. then reshaping.  Is there an extention to any of the above, like where, which is equivalent to 'in' comparisons?

Answer (score 6):

Python's one-line ternary operator syntax looks like this

```
variable = a if CONDITION else b
```

You can place this inside a list comprehension as well.  It's not clear what `val` is in your example, but I'm assuming it's a value you specified beforehand.

```
val = 2
A = [[val if A[i][j] < val else A[i][j] for j in range(n)] for i in range(m)]
```

Comment: This worked wondefully! I did have to do a type conversion back to np.float64 afterward. Otherwise it did exactly what I wanted.

Comment: Since `A` is an array, it is clearer if you use `A[i,j]` to index an element.